# Reading REST API JSON response using Spark Scala

Tags: json, scala, api, rest, apache-spark

I want to hit an API by applying some parameters from a dataframe, get the Json Response body, and from the body, pull out all the distinct values of a particular Key.
I then need to add this column into the first dataframe.

Suppose i have a dataframe like below:

```
  df1:

+-----+-------+--------+
| DB  | User  | UserID |
+-----+-------+--------+
| db1 | user1 |    123 |
| db2 | user2 |    456 |
+-----+-------+--------+
```

I want to hit a REST API by providing the column value of `Df1` as parameters.

If my parameters for URL is `db=db1` and `User=user1`(First record of `df1`),the response will be a json format of following format:

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "db": "db1"
      "User": "User1"
      "UserID": 123
      "Query": "Select * from A"
      "Application": "App1"
    },

    {
       "db": "db1"
      "User": "User1"
      "UserID": 123
      "Query": "Select * from B"
      "Application": "App2"
    }

        ]
}
```

From this json file, i want get distinct values of `Application` key as an array or list and attach it as a new column to `Df1`

My output will look similar to below:

```
Final df:

+-----+-------+--------+-------------+
| DB  | User  | UserID |    Apps     |
+-----+-------+--------+-------------+
| db1 | user1 |    123 | {App1,App2} |
| db2 | user2 |    456 | {App3,App3} |
+-----+-------+--------+-------------+
```

I have come up with a high level plan on how to achieve it.

1. Add a new column called response URL built from multiple columns in input.
2. Define a scala function that takes in URL and return an array of application and convert it to UDF.
3. Create another column by applying the UDF by passing response URL.

Since i am pretty new to scala-spark and have never worked with REST APIs, can someone please help me here on achieving the result please.

Any other idea or suggestion is always welcome.

I am using spark 1.6.

Comment: is below solution helps ?

Comment: @Srinivas the solution looks perfect..thanks!. i haven't tried it out yet...issue with accessing the API..will update as soon as i try it out

Comment: post if you face any issue. & upvote or accept if it helps .. :)

Comment: is it not working ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code, You may need to write logic to invoke reset api. once you get result next process is simple.

```
scala> val df = Seq(("db1","user1",123),("db2","user2",456)).toDF("db","user","userid")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [db: string, user: string, userid: int]

scala> df.show(false)
+---+-----+------+
|db |user |userid|
+---+-----+------+
|db1|user1|123   |
|db2|user2|456   |
+---+-----+------+


scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def invokeRestAPI(db:String,user: String) = {
    import org.json4s._
    import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

    // Write your invoke logic & for now I am hardcoding your sample json here.
    val json_data = parse("""{"data":[ {"db": "db1","User": "User1","UserID": 123,"Query": "Select * from A","Application": "App1"},{"db": "db1","User": "User1","UserID": 123,"Query": "Select * from B","Application": "App2"}]}""")

   (json_data \\ "data" \ "Application").extract[Set[String]].toList
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

invokeRestAPI: (db: String, user: String)List[String]

scala> val fetch = udf(invokeRestAPI _)
fetch: org.apache.spark.sql.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,ArrayType(StringType,true),List(StringType, StringType))

scala> df.withColumn("apps",fetch($"db",$"user")).show(false)
+---+-----+------+------------+
|db |user |userid|apps        |
+---+-----+------+------------+
|db1|user1|123   |[App1, App2]|
|db2|user2|456   |[App1, App2]|
+---+-----+------+------------+
```